# How to deal with a user input string that gives an "unprintable ascii character found in source file" error when pasted into Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ascii

I am working on an app that lets the user paste in text and then the app processes that text.

With a certain text string I am getting an "unprintable ascii character found in source file" error. The unprintable character appears to be a tab, but I'm not sure. Anyway, it is causing problems when I try to process the text.

How can I filter out this or other unprintable characters when I first save the string in a variable?

Or is there another way to deal with this?

Comment: Either modify it somehow converting to the format that is supported by Xcode and convert back to the format you want to use in runtime or work with resource files instead.

Comment: This is user input that is crashing my app. Something, possibly a tab, in the user input is crashing the app. I pasted that strange user input into xcode and got that error. How can I modify the user input after it is saved as a string in the variable, so that later, when I try to process it, it doesn't crash the app? In other words, how can I detect and filter out that bad character?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26080815/35499). This talks about breaking a Swift String on non-printable characters so it should be close to what you want.

Comment: @webmagnets if you have not solved this yet would you mind pasting an example string that crashes your program and an example situation that causes the crash (so we can super easily reproduce your issue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way to do it.

This version also allows new line characters.

```
func convertString(string: String) -> String {
  var data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
  return NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as! String
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interested in keeping printable ASCII characters, then this code should work.

```
extension String {
    func printableAscii() -> String {
        return String(bytes: filter(self.utf8){$0 >= 32}, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Note this will filter tabs and line feeds too which may not be expected. Unprintable ASCII are any values less than 0x20. Here is a Playground screen capture.

[image]