# swift - Unprintable ASCII character found in source file

Tags: encode

This code:

```
var str = "ぴ"   //Japanese: pi
```

xcode report compilation error:

> Unprintable ASCII character found in source file

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What to do to not report errors

Comment: Well that is not an ascii character

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
func convertString(string: String) -> String {
   var data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
   return NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as! String
}
```

From [How to deal with a user input string that gives an "unprintable ascii character found in source file" error when pasted into Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628813/how-to-deal-with-a-user-input-string-that-gives-an-unprintable-ascii-character)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for the people who are using windows keyboard with mac system.

[image]
While typing you might have unknowingly clicked the right-click key in your keyboard, which will create the Unprintable ASCII character that is causing the Unprintable ASCII character found in the source file error.

To check this go to find（cmd+F） and click the right-click key and you can find them in your class and delete those characters and the error will be gone.

Thanks

Comment: Amazing--I have this exact keyboard and it was this exact key character in the source causing the error. It didn't look like anything onscreen. Not sure how I would've found it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4:**

```
func convertString(string: String) -> String {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: true)
    return NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)! as String
}
```

Comment: He's talking about an XCode editor issue, not an issue dealing with some "string".  I hit this one a lot too - no idea how the unprintable characters are getting into my source files, must be some weird hotkey combo...

Answer (score 0):

In a Playground your line won't give you an error as it is, since it uses UTF-8 encoding by default. In a regular project your trusty File inspector will allow you to define the Text Encoding in the Text Settings section. I recommend to use some version of Unicode, probably UTF-8 if your app will deal primarily with western languages and UTF-16 if you have a lot of text constants in asian languages.

This just for the record since this is an old question and you probably found a working solution years ago.