# Read binary file to string

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

How can I read **binary** (not a text) file to string?
I need something similar what `cat -v file.dat` command does.

Comment: What do you mean by binary? is it a sequence of bytes `[UInt8]`?

Comment: @LeoDabus I mean any non-text file. It could be an image or audio or any other data file that I want import as text. In other words, I want to extract any text from data file.

Comment: You can't convert any `Data` into regular text (utf8 encoding). You will need to use base64Encoding. `data.base64EncodedString()`

Comment: If you have a sequence of bytes `Data(bytes).base64EncodedString()`

Comment: @LeoDabus Imagine you are opening any mp3 file in Sublime Text. You will see some text output in the editor. I need to convert NSData which is not a text to text output.

Comment: I know know what is your goal but if you need to send your data as text you need to use `base64EncodedString()` method

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't need to send it. I'm not trying to serialize it. Please try 'cat -v' on any non text file...

Comment: Just use `.ascii` encoding.  `String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, will try now

Comment: Note that if you open a data file with SImpleText it will use `macOSRoman` encoding

Comment: @LeoDabus Perfect. That was exactly what I was looking for. Please add your comment as an answer, so I could accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use String initializer `init?(data: Data, encoding: String.Encoding)` to convert your data to string or `init?<S>(bytes: S, encoding: String.Encoding) where S : Sequence, S.Element == UInt8` if you want to convert a byte sequence. Just make sure you use `.ascii` string encoding:

```
let string = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
```

Comment: Ascii is a bad choice because it contains non-printable characters. If you really want to "view" the data you should use encodings with a constrained character set like base 64 or hex.

Comment: @sundance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)

Comment: I know what cat is. The point is if you decode arbitrary binary data with ascii encoding you WILL get non-printable characters. It is possible to filter out those characters (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628813/how-to-deal-with-a-user-input-string-that-gives-an-unprintable-ascii-character) but then you will skip some of the original data.

Comment: @sundance thanks for the down voting. Note that If you look at comments You will notice that I did suggest base64EncodedString() before you posted your answer but thats not what OP needed. Note that down voting my answer won't make yours better

Comment: Note that this will *not* do what the OP keeps saying they want (repeated references to `cat -v`).  Specifically it will not translate non-printable/non-ascii characters into something useful.  ` -v Display non-printing characters so they are visible.`

Comment: @DavidBerry I've just posted what OP asked me to post. I twas originally posted as a comment. If you know what OP needs post your answer

Comment: I get that, just wanted to point out that it doesn't do the same thing he *says* he's asking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've somehow read the file contents into a `Data`, you can use:

```
extension UInt8 {
    var printableAscii : String {
        switch self {
        case 0..<32:    return "^" + (self + 64).printableAscii
        case 127:       return "^?"
        case 32..<128:  return String(bytes: [self], encoding:.ascii)!
        default:        return "M-" + (self & 127).printableAscii
        }
    }
}

extension Collection where Element == UInt8 {
    var printableAscii : String {
        return self.map { $0.printableAscii } .joined()
    }
}

let string = data.printableAscii
```

to turn the bytes of the data into the marginally legible format that `cat -v` produces.

Comment: Why not simply `.joined()` instead of reducing the array of Strings? Btw there is an extra parentheses. And Swift is type inferred to convert the data into an array of bytes you can simply initialize a new Array with the data. `Array(data).map { $0.printableAscii }.joined()`

Comment: Because sometimes your brain gets stuck and doesn't think of the obvious solutions :)

Comment: `Data` conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` so it would be better to extend Collection of UInt8 elements. It would extend both bytes array and Data. `extension Collection where Element == UInt8 {
    var printableAscii : String {
        return map { $0.printableAscii }.joined()
    }
}`

Comment: Actually, given that Data is now a `Collection<UInt8>` the extension can be simplified to `self.map` as well.  Good point.

Comment: Now if you can only find a better way to do `String([Character(UnicodeScalar(self))])` :)

Comment: @DavidBerry. Thank you for the answer, David. I tried both answers and Leo's answer works faster: 0.007541 vs 15.376013, so I will keep his answer as accepted.

Comment: Yeah, it'll be much faster, it just won't do what you originally asked for.  What Leo's answer does is essentially just `cat file.dat`.  Also be wary of time comparisons in playgrounds, they're mostly meaningless :)

Comment: @DavidBerry regarding `String([Character(UnicodeScalar(self))])` you don't need to convert the Character into an array to convert it to string `String(Character(UnicodeScalar(self)))`. Btw that would only be needed if you wanted to convert the UnicodeScalar to UnicodeScalarView `String(String.UnicodeScalarView([UnicodeScalar(self)]))`

Comment: Thought that was one of the iterations I went through to get there, but apparently not.  Not sure which is better `String(Character(UnicodeScalar(self)))` or `String(bytes:[self], .ascii)!` so just gonna leave it alone for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file with

```
let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath)
```

and then convert the data to a base 64 string with

```
let string = data.base64EncodedString()
```

or to a hex string with

```
let string = data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
```